# Display text to fill screen : Android

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to display a text, that that will use the maximum possible screen in the device, in both landscape and portrait mode. i am a beginner. how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

increase textsize of text and see the result.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did this already. Its just that i didn't increase the text sizing assuming it should automatically increase. But it didn't. :(. anyway thanks for the help. Got the problem sorted out.Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` and `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`. For more info look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#FILL_PARENT).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other responses. But if you want to be really up-to-date, use match_parent instead.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html

Answer (score 0):

android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"